# extracting non-empty value in ruby

Tags: ruby

```
pry(main)> s = {:a =>2, :d=>'foo', :x => '    ', :n => true, :z => nil}
=> {:a=>2, :d=>"foo"}
pry(main)> s.each do |k,v| p k unless v.empty? end

NoMethodError: undefined method `length' for 2:Fixnum
```

I understand it happens because fixnum does not have empty methods. Then how to solve this problem in a *slick* way, no nasty finding data type first and then check it? I want to print  those `k` where `v` has some value. Yes `true` is considered a value, but not bunch of spaces. For me "have value" means non-empty characters and boolean true.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "some value"? Does `true` have some value?

Comment: The reason it is not working is that Ruby does not know what you mean. And neither do we. What exactly do you mean by `empty?`. You mean `!nil?`? Which values do you list as "not having a value"? `nil`? Anything else?

Comment: @Casper thanks for the comment. Pl. see my revision

Comment: I have no idea what your desired output is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your updated comments, I think that is what you want.

```
s = {:a =>2, :d=>'foo', :x => '    ', :n => true, :z => nil}
s.each { |k,v| p(k) if !!v && !v.to_s.strip.empty? }
# :n
# :d
# :a
```

Comment: Thanks. Selected your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Quick solution:

```
s.each {|k,v| p k unless v.to_s.empty?}
```

Comment: As I said, I don't want to do data checking and also conversion

Comment: @JVK that looks like a perfect solution to me, it even covers the `nil` case very elegantly! You might want to loosen up your constraints.

Comment: @akuhn JVK considers the `'    '` a empty value.